# Key differences between Ruby and C

Tags: c, ruby

What are the key differences between Ruby and C?

Comment: If you can't tell then I don't think I want you working for me...

Comment: They are two completely different languages that have only one thing in common: the Ruby interpreter is written in C.

Comment: Is this homework or somesuch?

Comment: @ ROMANARMY nope ... Just came to mind while I started looking into "http://tryruby.org/"

Comment: New question; what are the key differences between a roast beef sandwich and ice cream.  Discuss.

Comment: @Ed Swangren LOL... Sorry for my lame question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are almost totally different.

**Ruby**

- Strong, dynamic typing
- Purely object oriented
- Automatic garbage collection and no pointers
- Interpreted (or JIT compilation with JRuby/IronRuby)
- Reflective
- Supports functional programming (closures, coroutines, etc.)
- No preprocessor or macros

**C**

- Weak, static typing
- Procedural (not object oriented)
- Not garbage collected and has pointers
- Compiled
- No reflection
- Does not support functional programming
- Has a preprocessor and supports macros

**[To Ruby From C and C++](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/to-ruby-from-c-and-c-/)**

Comment: Nice! So, Ruby doesn't have memory leaks

Comment: @72616b657368: All languages can have resource leaks.  Some languages just pick up after you more than others making such bugs less likely.

Comment: Note that Ruby can also be compiled completely ahead-of-time with JRuby or MacRuby. In any case, though, it is still substantially different from C in that there are many options in how the code is run.

Comment: Looks to me "reflection" is a strong feature in Ruby

Comment: @72616b657368 Reflection in Ruby is certainly powerful, especially when combined with Ruby's open classes.  However, be careful to use these features sparingly and only where they make sense!  "With great power comes great responsibility"

Answer (score 0):

Why do you ask? Do you have a specific project or goals in mind?

In addition to what others have already mentioned; I'd also say that some key differences to keep in mind is that the C family is much more portable....or rather, much easier to distribute the finished software. C programs will also be much faster than Ruby...whether that is important or not depends on what you are building (well, that's ALWAYS important, but it isn't a make or break proposition for a lot of programs).

Ruby is just simply a beautiful language to work with (do not underestimate the importance of a language that *works with you*); developing programs is much quicker in Ruby than C ( C is a compiled language, so that is to be expected )...Ruby is also a pretty simple language to learn; most people consider C to be fairly tough for newbies to pick up.

-- edit --
wow, just saw this was a 3 year old thread....my bad